# Upload to a specific media folder created by FileBird Lite

Tags: plugin-development, images, uploads, media-library

I have an import that runs in the background of my server through cron. I have a plugin called FileBird Lite (https://ninjateam.org/wordpress-media-library-folders/) that helps create folders and such to organise the imagery into folders.

Does anyone know how I can programatically add the images uploaded through the cron job into a FileBird Lite folder.

Say it is books I am uploading to a library, I would want the folder to be called Books, and as the images are uploaded for each book, it would be automatically placed into the Books folder.

Appreciate this may not directly tie with WordPress.StackExchange.com, if there is a better place for this question to be asked please let me know and I can ask the question there.

Comment: What do you need help with: finding the folder on disk? Or getting FileBird Lite to choose the right folder for you, for the file you've just been given?

Comment: Oh, these are virtual folders not real filesystem folders? You'd need to work out how those are stored, or find a FireBird API to manage this.

Comment: Bizarrely the image when placed into folders maintains the initial upload URL, so it is not physically placed into a folder. It is like done through the post ID or something, example URL: /wp-content/uploads/2022/11/book-one.png

Comment: @Rup - exactly mate, not sure at this point how it is handled. What hooks can be called to action it remotely (not in Dashboard -> Media).

Comment: There's some very basic developer docs here: https://ninjateam.gitbook.io/filebird/developer-zone/functions I'd guess the folder is stored in post meta somewhere, and probably somewhere else too that's more efficient to search than postmeta.

Comment: The URL when filtered to a folder looks like so: /wp-admin/upload.php?mode=list&attachment-filter&m=0&fbv=7&s&action=-1&paged=1&action2=-1&affected&_ajax_nonce=b989cdf71b&ps

Comment: I will take a look at those docs pages :) Thanks @Rup